# How to redirect subdomain to www domain using global.asax MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax

I have a website under IIS7 with catch all subdomain as *.mydomain.com
but some sites randomize subdomains like:

- www2.mydomain.com
- w.w.w.mydomain.com
- etc.mydomain.com

Any subdomain works perfectly loading my MVC page, but the google indexing doubles the url, because have two url differents.

I would redirect permanently "301" any subdomain to www.mydomain.com using global.asax keeping the url and query string. e.g.

- www2.mydomain.com/Controller/Action/ID?query=asb TO
  **www.mydomain.com/Controller/Action/ID?query=asb**
- w.w.w.mydomain.com/Controller/Action/ID?query=asb TO **www.mydomain.com/Controller/Action/ID?query=asb**

I want not to use IIS7 redirect because I will customize with C# the what subdomains should not be redirected.

I don´t like to create page base for all controller.

Comment: What are the reasons for doing it in Globas.asax, and not in the web container?

Comment: He has conditions on when to rewrite the URL, so he is using C# code to make that determination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using IIS, you should be able to achieve this with ARR.

Example:

```
<rule name="SubDomain" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\w+)\.mine\.co\.uk$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Reference: http://forums.iis.net/p/1155754/1895646.aspx

Comment: This is what I would do.  You can customize the match pattern to skip the rewrite on certain sub-domains.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I installed the rewrite_2.0_rtw_x64.msi (IIS7 Rewrite Module) and I created a specific rule called 'Canonical domain name'. The module asked me primary domain name (with or without www) and done! All subdomains will been redirect. It worked, thanks again.